# Failed to set PHP CodeSniffer installed_paths Config issue at Magento2.4 installation

Tags: php, installation, composer, magento2.4

I tried to install Magento2 using Composer.

After run

```
$ sudo composer create-project --repository=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition magento
```

the installation showed the error Failed to set PHP CodeSniffer installed_paths Config.
[image]

I tried

```
$sudo composer global require "squizlabs/php_codesniffer=*"

$composer global config bin-dir --absolute
```

Then I removed /var/www/html and created again.
Then I tried

```
$sudo composer create-project --repository=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition magento
```

It shows same error.

Does anyone know of a solution?

I'm using AWS EC2. After launching the instance, I run the following commands.

```
$sudo apt update
$sudo apt install nginx
$sudo systemctl stop nginx.service
$sudo systemctl start nginx.service
$sudo systemctl enable nginx.servic
$sudo apt install php7.4-fpm php7.4-common php7.4-mysql php7.4-gmp php7.4-curl php7.4-intl php7.4-mbstring php7.4-xmlrpc php7.4-gd php7.4-xml php7.4-cli php7.4-zip
$sudo systemctl restart php7.4-fpm nginx
$curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin --filename=composer
```

Before restarting hp7.4-fpm and nginx, I edit /etc/php/7.4/fpm/php.ini depending on https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/prereq/php-settings.html

OS:Ubuntu20.04  Web server: Nginx1.18.0 php:7.4.16 DB:RDS Mysql8.0